# How to avoid true=false condition

Tags: coq

I am using function(list_max l) from standard library and proving following lemma. I am facing problem at following point, Plz guide me.

```
 Fixpoint g_fun (l : list nat) :=
  match l with
 | nil => 1
 | b::nil=> b
 | b::t => gcd b (g_fun t)
end.
 Lemma gc1: forall (l : list nat),
 l<>nil -> list_max l = 0-> g_fun l=0.
 Proof.
 intros. induction l. unfold g_fun.
```

Comment: Guide: Please learn to write in English and to articulate yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it, but I think I would prove two auxiliary lemmas first:

1. if `list_max l = 0`, then `l` is a list with only zeros [EDIT: or `l` is empty]; proving this will likely go through `list_max_le`.
2. `g_fun [n; n; ...; n] = g_fun [n]`; this should be a simple induction together with `Nat.gcd_diag`.

If `l` is empty, your lemma is actually false, because `list_max nil = 0` and `g_fun nil = 1`. Otherwise the lemma is an easy corollary of these two facts.

Comment: I have proved your first suggested lemma ( Lemma list_m0 l : list_max l = 0 -> forall a, nth a l 0 = 0.) But when I write second lemma(Lemma gcdn_n: forall (n : nat) (l : list nat), g_fun [n; n; ...; n] = g_fun [n]). I get Syntax Error: Lexer: Undefined token.

Comment: @joshanbeha, Yes, the notation `[n; n; ...; n]` doesn't actually exist. You can represent it in several ways, but since you used `forall a, nth a l 0 = 0` in your first lemma, it's probably a good idea to use `forall a, nth a l n = n` in your second one.

Comment: I am applying command (rewrite <- Nat.eq_le_incl) to convert                
   nth a l n = n  to nth a l n <= n. But get message (setoid rewrite failed). How I can convert equality relation into less or equal relation?

Comment: Lemma n_gcd l n : g_fun  l = n -> forall a, nth a l n = n.
Proof.
intros n0 a.
destruct (le_gt_dec (length l) a) as [h1 | h2].
  rewrite nth_overflow. auto. assumption.

Comment: 1. You should `apply Nat.eq_le_incl` , not rewrite. The statement `n <= m` is not an equality or an equivalence. 2. The Lemma `n_gcd` you wrote in the last comment is not true. The `gcd` of a list can be `n` without the list being composed only of `n`. For example, `g_fun (1 :: 2 :: nil)` is `1`, but `1 :: 2 :: nil` has an element that is different from `1`. What I suggested you prove was actually the other direction of that implication, and it only holds when `l` is nonempty: `l <> nil -> (forall a, nth a l n = n) -> g_fun l = n`.

Comment: You mean to prove lemma (Lemma gc1: forall (l : list nat),
 list_max l = 0-> g_fun l=0).  I need two sub lemmas(Lemma list_m0 l : list_max l = 0 -> forall a, nth a l 0 = 0) ) &( l <> nil -> (forall a, nth a l n = n) -> g_fun l = n).

Comment: @joshanbeha That's what I meant yes, except that `forall (l : list nat), list_max l = 0-> g_fun l=0)` is false when the list is empty, as I mentioned above. So you could prove `forall (l : list nat), l <> nil -> list_max l = 0-> g_fun l=0)` instead. In that case the proof is a simple application of those two auxiliar lemmas.